# Sending a URL request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, url

I have a device which is connected via ethernet and receives settings via a web browser interface.
When the user clicks "Update Settings" the button calls a URL which has the format

```
{{IP}}/cgi-bin/webinterfaceSharedMemoryClient.cgi?key=value&key=value&key=value
```

where the `{{IP}}` is the set IP of the device.

Does anyone have an idea how I could send this using Ruby, without using a web browser?

Comment: Depending on the method used, whether it's POST or GET, you can use a number of different libraries or gems: OpenURI is the easiest, things like HTTPClient or Curb are nicely featured but a bit more complex, down to Net::HTTP which is very powerful but spirals into complexity quickly. OpenURI doesn't support POST, but the rest do.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "IP/cgi-bin/webinterfaceSharedMemoryClient.cgi?key=value&key=value&key=value"
response = open(url) { |io| io.read }
```

With more control, use `Net::HTTP`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a library called Net in ruby which should do what you want. The simplest usage would be something like:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://#.#.#.#/cgi-bin/webinterfaceSharedMemoryClient.cgi?key=value&key=value&key=value')
Net::HTTP.get(uri) # => results
```

this is essentially from the Ruby 2.0 documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) gem.  Here's an example:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get "http://www.example.org/"
page.link_with(:text => 'More information...').click
```

Comment: "wrong header line format"
Each of the above appear to work in a round about way though it would appear I am missing something. Thanks